# How do I import GMP that was installed using homebrew?

Tags: c++, xcode, gmp

I installed GMP 6.1.2_2 using homebrew on my mac, but when I write
`#include <gmp>` in xcode, it cannot find it. How do I make xcode see GMP?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell your compiler where to look for includes. If using gcc or clang then that is the `-I` compiler option.