# How do I install GMP into XCode with Brew?

Tags: c++, xcode, homebrew, gmp

I am trying to use GMP and MPFR in an XCode project. I installed Homebrew, and then installed the libraries with `brew install gmp` and `brew install mpfr`, which seemed to be successful. However, when I `#include <gmp.h>`, it says that the file is not found. I saw a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51224876/how-do-i-import-gmp-that-was-installed-using-homebrew), which suggested that I need to tell the compiler where to find it, but I don't know how to do that and there weren't many details.

Edit: I am on an M1 Mac.

Comment: If you're on a silicon mac (m1/m2), you need to add the include path: `/opt/homebrew/include` to the project's include search paths. search in build settings for `header search paths` and add this directory in there.

Comment: I'm not seeing why that advice is exclusive to ARM macs. I doubt XCode searches homebrew paths by default on x86.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using homebrew, the default behavior for intel macs is to install homebrew into `/usr/local`. This means that headers in that environment are in `/usr/local/include`.

The default set of search paths for the compiler include this directory, so if you install homebrew software on intel macs, it will automatically find the appropriate headers in that location. It will also *link* against software in `/usr/local/lib`, so it's really convenient - homebrew software tends to just build and link in this environment.

On silicon macs (m1/m2), the default behavior changes. When you install *native* packages, they will get installed into `/opt/homebrew`.

The header directory will be `/opt/homebrew/include` and the library directory will be `/opt/homebrew/lib`. Unfortunately neither folder will be part of the default build path, which will cause compilation and linking to fail.

In order to add the header folder to the build settings, you need to go to the `build settings` for the target.

In the `header search paths` add the header folder `/opt/homebrew/include`.

In the `library search paths`, add the library folder `/opt/homebrew/lib`

If you're using Makefiles, the corresponding items would be: `-I/opt/homebrew/include` and `-L/opt/homebrew/lib`

If you're using cmake, the corresponding variables that would need to be set would be: `include_directories(/opt/homebrew/include)` and `link_directories(/opt/homebrew/lib)`.

finally…

If you're using rosetta2 versions of homebrew (these would be intel binaries running on silicon macs), then these versions will get installed into `/usr/local`, and will build; as long as you're building binaries for intel. This is a less than trivial situation. There are a *lot* of things that end up being trickier in this environment - well beyond this answer.

Comment: I added those paths to "Header Search Paths" and "Library Search Paths" under both Debug and Release. This resolved the issue of the header file not being found, but it fails on build. It seems to me that the issue is that the linker cannot find the library files because it says that all of the mpfr functions are "undefined symbol" and it also had a linker failure with exit code 1. As far as rosetta 2, I'm sure sure and I don't know how to check that, but I'm guessing it's native because I installed it a few days ago using the command from their website.

Comment: On the presumption you're building for mac silicon, you need to add the libgmp library (and gmp c++ library), by adding `-lgmpxx -lgmp` to `Other Linker Flags`. If you get an error such as: `ignoring file /opt/homebrew/lib/libgmpxx.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64`, it indicates you're attempting to build an intel binary, so you'll need an intel version of libgmp. That's an even bigger info-dump of an answer.

Comment: I added those flags, but I'm still getting the same errors. I don't get any any errors about arm or x86_64. They're all `Undefined symbol: _mpfr_add` or something like that, except the last one which is `Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: The error output is somewhat important for debugging. Once I added the libraries to Other Linker Flags (on two lines - one for `-lgmpxx` and one for `-lgmp`), it linked for me. The slightly more complex answer involves going to 'Build Phases' -> 'Link Binary with Libraries', and add a reference to libgmp.dylib and libgmp++.dylib in `/opt/homebrew/lib`. I also needed to disable 'Use Hardened Runtime' for the binary, in order to have it run.

Comment: It has now worked; my mistake was that I only put in the /opt paths, whereas it needed both /opt and /usr/local paths. Not sure why, but it's working now.